# How to delete an empty row that exists in a table or a frame?

Tags: libreoffice

In *LibreOffice Writer* v4.2.7.2: How do I delete an empty row that exists in a table or a frame?

I created a table in a frame. But an empty line appears above & below the table:
[image]

### My attempts to delete those empty lines (non worked):

1. Using the `Del` key - in various ways
2. Using the *Find & Replace* dialog and a regexp pattern, as suggested [here](http://www.zyxware.com/articles/3498/how-to-remove-the-extra-space-and-new-line-in-a-libreoffice-document).
   The regexp patterns which I had tried are:

   - `^$` which worked only for the empty lines which were *outside* the frame.
   - `^[\r\n]$` which simply didn't work at all.
   - `^\W+$` also didn't work.